# I need help with iMac RAM improvement guidelines and principles

Tags: memory

I have several iMacs at my workplace where I'm tasked with upgrading the RAMs of these. I have several questions regarding this process.

1. Can I mix 4 GB sticks with 8 GB sticks?
2. Do I need to respect the PC3-10600 specification or could I install a PC3-12800 stick to a model that says it needs 10600? Can I mix these, like having 10600 in two slots and 12800 in the other two?
3. What does **unbuffered** and **nonparity** mean? Or more precisely, how to make sure a specific model I find available online conforms to these requirements? E.g. [this documentation](https://www.kingston.com/datasheets/kvr16ls11_4.pdf) for a Kingston stick does not at all mention these properties as far as I was able to decipher the document.

Comment: Golden rule: When buying RAM for Macs, buy RAM for Macs. Don't try figure out the details yourself, or half the time it just won't work. See [How to find which RAM to get for my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1543730/how-to-find-which-ram-to-get-for-my-computer)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to reply that:

1. you can mix ram modules with different frequencies and different sizes, but it is advisable not to do this
2. I advise you to respect PC3-10600 because it is always a good idea to keep the standards already installed by increasing the capacity
3. I also advise you to choose compatible memories to visit sites such as https://www.datamemorysystems.com/apple-memory/